# FASM cannot pass structure to function

Tags: assembly, macros, x86, structure, fasm

I have an assembler code in fasm like this:

```
struct TestStruct
    test dd 0
ends

proc TestProc theArg:TestStruct
     mov eax,[theArg.test]
     ret 4
endp


start:

virtual at 0
  lpTest TestStruct
end virtual

lea eax, [lpTest]
invoke TestProc, eax

invoke  ExitProcess, 0

.end start
```

So, i'm trying to pass a struct `TestStruct` as a reference to the `TestProc`, so it would be something identical to this in C:

```
int _stdcall TestProc(TestStruct * arg)
{
     return arg->test;
}

...
TestStruct arg;
TestProc(&arg);
```

i declared it in the stack here

```
virtual at 0
  lpTest TestStruct
end virtual
```

But when i compile, i get the compilation error like so:

`Error Extra character on line: label ..arg?WJ TestStruct` this error appears on this line:

`proc TestProc theArg:TestStruct`

How to pass this structure by reference correctly?

Answer (score 0):

with

```
virtual at 0
  lpTest TestStruct
end virtual
```

you set the start-address of this virtual area to `0`, so `lpTest` will be zero too and `lea eax, [lpTest]` is equivalent to `lea eax, [0]` (which is equivalent to `mov eax, 0`, you do not want this). But there is a trick:

```
virtual at esp
  lpTest TestStruct
end virtual
```

now the address of `lpTest` is `esp` and `lea eax, [lpTest]` will be compiled to `lea eax, [esp]`.

By the way: `lea eax, [esp]` is equivalent to `mov eax, esp`.